Player sprite becomes smaller during attack animation (Java)
I'm developing a 2D game in Java using Java Swing, and I've run into an issue with my player character's attack animation. The player has both movement and attack animations:
Movement sprites: 16x16 pixels
Attack sprites: 80x80 pixels
The movement animations work perfectly, and the player displays at the correct size. However, when I trigger the attack animation, the player sprite becomes very small, even though the attack sprites are larger than the movement sprites. The player goes through the complete axe attack animation however he becomes extremely small during the animation. Any insight would be greatly appreciated thanks !
Here's the relevant code from my Player class:
package entity;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import main.GamePanel;
import main.KeyHandler;
import object.Axe_Object;
import object.SuperObject;

public class Player extends Entity{
    public BufferedImage spriteSheet;
    public BufferedImage spriteSheetAxe;
    GamePanel gp;
    KeyHandler keyH;
    public int screenX;
    public int screenY;
    public SuperObject currentWeapon;
    
    
    // Player inventory and Game Mechanics
    private Inventory inventory;
    
    
    // Arrays to hold animation frames for each direction
    public BufferedImage[] upFrames = new BufferedImage[8];
    public BufferedImage[] downFrames = new BufferedImage[8];
    public BufferedImage[] leftFrames = new BufferedImage[8];
    public BufferedImage[] rightFrames = new BufferedImage[8];
    
    // Arrays to hold attacks animations
    public BufferedImage[] upAxeFrames = new BufferedImage[12];
    public BufferedImage[] downAxeFrames = new BufferedImage[12];
    public BufferedImage[] leftAxeFrames = new BufferedImage[12];
    public BufferedImage[] rightAxeFrames = new BufferedImage[6];
    
    private int frameIndex = 0; // To track the current frame
    private int frameCounter = 0; // control fame rate of animation
    private int frameDelay = 5; // How many game loops before switching frame
    public int numberOfKeys = 0;
    
    
    
    public Player(GamePanel gp, KeyHandler keyH) {
        this.gp = gp;
        this.keyH = keyH;
        screenX = gp.screenWidth / 2 - (gp.tileSize / 2);
        screenY = gp.screenHeight / 2 - (gp.tileSize / 2);
        
        solidArea = new Rectangle(8, 16, 16, 16); // x, y, width, height
        
        solidAreaDefaultX = solidArea.x;
        solidAreaDefaultY = solidArea.y;
        
        inventory = new Inventory();

        setDefaultValues();
        loadSpriteSheet();
        loadPlayerImages();
        loadPlayerAxeAttackImages();
    }
    
    private void loadSpriteSheet() {
        try {
            spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/walk.png"));
            spriteSheetAxe = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/axesprite.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error in loading the spritesheet");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    private void loadPlayerImages() {
        int x = 3;
        int upY = 18;
        int downY = 13;
        int rightY = 3;
        int leftY = 8;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            upFrames[i] = grabImage(x, upY, gp.originalTileSize, gp.originalTileSize);
            downFrames[i] = grabImage(x, downY, gp.originalTileSize, gp.originalTileSize);
            rightFrames[i] = grabImage(x, rightY, gp.originalTileSize, gp.originalTileSize);
            leftFrames[i] = grabImage(x, leftY, gp.originalTileSize, gp.originalTileSize);
                    
            x += 5;     
        }
        
    }
    
    
    // THIS IS THE PART CAUSING PROBLEMS
    private void loadPlayerAxeAttackImages() {
        int x = 3;
        int upY = 18;
        int downY = 13;
        int rightY = 3;
        int leftY = 8;
        
        // Load all up frames images for right swing
        
        rightAxeFrames[0] = grabImageAxeAttack(1, 1, 80, 80 );
        rightAxeFrames[1] = grabImageAxeAttack(2, 1, 80, 80 );
        rightAxeFrames[2] = grabImageAxeAttack(3, 1, 80, 80 );
        rightAxeFrames[3] = grabImageAxeAttack(4, 1, 80, 80);
        rightAxeFrames[4] = grabImageAxeAttack(5, 1, 80, 80 );
        rightAxeFrames[5] = grabImageAxeAttack(6, 1, 80, 80 );

        
    }


    public void setDefaultValues() {
        worldX = gp.tileSize * 10;
        worldY = gp.tileSize * 10;
        speed = 7;
        direction = "down";
        
        // PLAYER STATUS
        level = 1;
        maxNumberOfHP = 6;
        currentHp = maxNumberOfHP ;
        strength = 1; // The more strenght he has, the more damage he gives.
        dexterity = 1;  // The more dexterity he has, the less damage he receives.
        attack = 4;
        defense = 1;
        exp = 0;
        nextLevelExp = 5;
        coin = 0;
        currentWeapon = new Axe_Object();
        
        
    }
    
    public BufferedImage grabImage(int col, int row, int width, int height) {
        int x = (col * 16) - 16;
        int y = (row * 16) - 16;
        
        //System.out.printf("X coordinates: " + x + ", Y coordinates:", y);
        //System.out.println("Width: " + width + ", Height: " + height);
        return spriteSheet.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
    }
    
    public BufferedImage grabImageAxeAttack(int col, int row, int width, int height) {
        int x = (col * 80) - 80;
        int y = (row * 80) - 80;
        
        //System.out.printf("X coordinates: " + x + ", Y coordinates:", y);
        //System.out.println("Width: " + width + ", Height: " + height);
        return spriteSheetAxe.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
    }
    
    
    
    public void checkForObject() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gp.obj.length; i++) {
            if (gp.obj[i] != null) {
                if (this.gp.cChecker.objectCollision(this, gp.obj[i])) {
                    //  System.out.println("INTERSECTION BETWEEN PLAYER OBJECT");
                        pickUpObject(gp.obj[i]); // Pick up object if collided
                        gp.obj[i] = null; // Remove object from the map
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void pickUpObject(SuperObject obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (obj != null) {
            String objName = obj.name;
            
            switch (objName) {
            case "Key":
                gp.playSoundEffect(1);
                numberOfKeys++;
                break;
            }
            inventory.addItem(obj);
            System.out.println(obj.name + " picked up!");
        }
        
    }

    public void update() {
    
    if (keyH.showInventory == true) {
        inventory.showInventory();
    }   
        
    if (keyH.upPressed == true || keyH.downPressed == true || keyH.leftPressed == true || keyH.rightPressed == true) { 
        
        if (keyH.upPressed == true) {
            direction = "up";
            //worldY -= speed;
        } else if (keyH.downPressed == true) {
            direction = "down";
            //worldY += speed;
        } else if (keyH.leftPressed == true) {
            direction = "left";
        //  worldX -= speed;
        } else if (keyH.rightPressed == true) {
            direction = "right";
            //worldX += speed;
        } 
        
        
        // Check tile collision
        collisionOn = false;
        gp.cChecker.checkTile(this);
        
        if (collisionOn == false) {
            switch(direction) {
            case "up":
                worldY -= speed;
                break;
            case "down":
                worldY += speed;
                break;
            case "left":
                worldX -= speed;
                break;
            case "right":
                worldX += speed;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        checkForObject();
        
        // Update animation frame if player is moving
        frameCounter++;
        if (frameCounter >= frameDelay) { // Pass to next state of animation
            frameCounter = 0;
            frameIndex++;
            if (frameIndex >= 6) {
                frameIndex = 0;
            }
        } 
    } else {
        frameIndex =0;
    }
}
    

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        //g2.fillRect(screenX, screenY, gp.tileSize, gp.tileSize);
        BufferedImage image = null;
        switch (direction) {
        case "up":
            image = upFrames[frameIndex];
            
            if (attack()) {
                System.out.println("The player just attacked up");
                image = upAxeFrames[frameIndex];
            }
            break;
        case "down":
            image = downFrames[frameIndex];
            if (attack()) {
                System.out.println("The player just attacked down");
                image = downAxeFrames[frameIndex];
            }
            break;
        case "left":
            image = leftFrames[frameIndex];
            if (attack()) {
                System.out.println("The player just attacked left");
                image = leftAxeFrames[frameIndex];
            }
            break;
        case "right":
            image = rightFrames[frameIndex];
            if (attack()) {
                System.out.println("The player just attacked right");
                image = rightAxeFrames[frameIndex];
            }
            break;
        }
        
        g2.drawImage(image, screenX, screenY, gp.tileSize, gp.tileSize, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean attack() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        if (keyH.weaponAttack) {
            return true;
            
        }
        
        return false;
        
    }
    

}


This is the line where you actually draw the player:
g2.drawImage(image, screenX, screenY, gp.tileSize, gp.tileSize, null);

As you can see in the documentation, there are several versions of this method. You've picked the one that takes 6 arguments, (Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer). And for the width and height parameters, you passed gp.tileSize. That means "Take this image and scale it to this size before you draw it". So your 80x80 attack frames get scaled down to your tile size of (I assume) 16x16.
However, there is also a version of drawImage which doesn't take an image  size. Try this:
g2.drawImage(image, screenX, screenY, null);

Now every frame will be drawn in its original size.
However, you might now see a different problem: The frame is not where it should be. The larger sprites are too far to the right and too far down. That's because the coordinates we pass are the top-left corner of the sprite. So when you have spritesheets of non-uniform size, then you need to define a pivot point for each frame and take that into account when calculating the screen position. You didn't show us your sprites, so I don't know where their pivot points are. If they are always in the center of the frame, you could do this:
g2.drawImage(image, screenX - image.getWidth() / 2, screenY - image.getHeight() / 2, null);

Now every frame will be drawn centered on the screenX:screenY point.
